# Excel stop working when referencing ListObjects and ListColumns

Tags: excel, vba

I created a table and set name "Table1" like this:

ID ---------------------- Name

1-------------------Peter Parker

2-------------------Wonder Woman

3-------------------Thanos

I tried to refer to ListObjects object in 2 ways:

Way 1:

```
MsgBox Range("Table1").ListObject.Name
```

Way 2:

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name
```

Both way gave the same result: "Table1"

But **Way 2 caused excel stop working when i closed excel application.**

And also when i use Way 1 but refer to ListColumns

```
MsgBox Range("Table1").ListObject.ListColumns("Name").Range(2)
```

**I got similar crash "Excel stop working" when closed excel** although the result still right: "Peter Parker"

Why i got that error and how to refer to ListColumns ?
Thanks a lot !

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba6p7.jpg)
[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eDCT.jpg)

[ResultListColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyjqa.jpg)

Comment: From the discussion in @Rawrplus: it sounds like your file my be corrupt. Try creating a new file and then implement Rawrplus's solution. Don't not save as a new workbook.. if the file is corrupt, copying it or renaming it wont work. You will have to export your modules/forms to the new file

Comment: I found the reason: I installed a tools for excel, and that tools caused that error. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to refer to a `ListObject` would be via a variable.

```
Dim tbl as ListObject 
Set tbl = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").ListObjects("Your Table Name")
```

So now you can easily refer to your table *(and the `ListColumns`)* via the variable.

```
tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange ' returns DataBodyRange of the 2nd column
```

Comment: I still got an error: "Microsoft Office Excel has stopped working" when i closed excel. Meanwhile, when i refer in way 1, that error didn't appear.

Comment: Does that error also trigger if you load Excel in "safe" mode? Either hold CTRL when you launch it, or run `excel /safe`. If the error disappears, then the problem is with an add-in.

Comment: Is the sheet password protected, does it have protected ranges? How do you start the VBA code?

Comment: I found the reason: I installed a tools for excel, and that tools caused that error. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @MinhTran could you mark the answer as 'solved' then please, so the question doesn't stay open? Thank you! :)